# Redshift Versus Luminosity

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, gravitational-redshift, luminosity

I understand that there is a relation between the proper distance of a cosmic object and its "measurable" redshift, i.e. once you know the value of the redshift parameter z, then you actually know how far this object from you. If this is correct then why do have to find another way of measuring the distances and use the luminosity "method"?

Comment: Peter's answer gives a good answer to why we need to consider luminosities. I'll add, though, that we use the luminosity method the other way around -- given that everything is calibrated, it is often more useful to know how much dimmer an object will be than how many proper gigaparsecs away it is. Similarly, one would use the angular diameter distance if one was interested in how big something appeared. In fact, the proper distance is probably the least useful distance measure, and it is also the least directly connected to observations.

Comment: Would you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Cosmic expansion is just one source of red shift, however, cosmic expansion dominates for all but "nearby" objects.

So can you use red shift alone for remote objects? Yes, you can.

However, the distance scale must also be calibrated, for the Hubble parameter must be experimentally determined. Hence the interest in "standard candles".

See also https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/help/zdef.html

Comment: So basically  we can determine the distances with redshift alone, very consistent. Oh.. The link you suggested  wrote that luminosity method  need the scale factor (it's a function of the scale factor) hence I don't think that it is the method for determing the scale factor. Anyway, you didn't say that explicitly, you referred to "the standard candles".

Comment: The absolute luminosity is "known" for the standard candles, a phrase you can search on. Knowing the absolute luminosity plus the measured luminosity allows you to calculate calibrated distances as far out as your standard candles can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are dealing with very large values with very large errors, yes one can estimate how distant objects are from only the red shift.  At least you will have a ball-park number, two methods to try are

t = 2(Universe age Gyrs)/(1+(1+z)^2)

which will give you the time of the emission from the big bang according to Carmeli. So if we use a universe of 15 Gyrs and a redshift of 0 we calculate the age of the emission from the BB of 15 Gyrs.

The second method requires more assumptions where

t = (2/3) x (1/H_0 x Omega_m x (1+z)3/2)

Here H_0 is the current Hubble constant, Omega_m is the current, normalized matter density, z is your redshift and x mean multiply. This is from the P.J.E.Peebles book, page 102. You can select a H_0 of anywhere from 62.3 to about 73 and an Omega_m of anywhere from 0.02 to 0.3. Unfortunately, such freedom gives you most any distance you like.

Neither approximation is really much good beyond a z=2.